# Is there anything I should know before changing out my ram sticks? Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation, 13.04, ram

Okay 1st off let me start by saying I have only been using Ubuntu..or Linux in general for about 3 months but in an effort to get the most out of my old tower I have decided to upgrade my ram ..I have read that some Linux distros install into ram so will anything be missing or corrupted?

Will I have to re-partition anything ..and I don’t know if this will matter but I started out with a "recommended install" in the installation wizard with Ubuntu 12.10 and then auto upgraded to Ubuntu 13.40

The motherboard I am using is an MSI MS-7181 VER 2.0
The ram I have is 2 stick of 512mb of DDR pc3200 184pin non EEC

The ram I will be installing is  CT2KIT12864Z40B  2GB kit (1GBx2), 184-pin DIMM

any help you can give will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You shouldn"t have to repartition anything if you're just upgrading RAM. The partitions exist on your Hard Drive. (Or Solid State Drive, USB, etc. that you installed the Operating System on.)

- Just be sure your RAM matches what is required for your motherboard (which it looks like you have). That includes pins and speed.
- Be careful of electro-static Discharge (static electricity), this is
  best prevented by wearing a grounding strap or touching the case
  before touching any components.
- Also, when handling the RAM sticks
  (modules), only touch the plastic edges. Don't touch any metal
  surface on the module, especially the contacts that go into the slot.
  Touching them can damage the module and cause corrosion.

Comment: And most important, unplug the tower first. :)

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is permanently installed on RAM. RAM only stores data while it has power. Changing or upgrading your RAM will not affect your linux installation

Comment: but will i have to repartition anything